# send ALL the value using a ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs, observable

Following this exemple

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
const subject = new ReplaySubject(3); // buffer 3 values for new subscribers

subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(5);

// Logs:
// observerA: 1
// observerA: 2
// observerA: 3
// observerA: 4
// observerB: 2
// observerB: 3
// observerB: 4
// observerA: 5
// observerB: 5
```

I would like to be able to buffer not only the last 3 values, but that any new subscriber will receive ALL the value that were sent. how can I achieve this ?

I tried  `const subject = new ReplaySubject();` and it does work apparently, but there is no place i can confirm that it is supposed to as in the docs they just say what are the parameters

Comment: if you want to buffer all value, it will cause heavy memory usage.

Comment: I know, but I also know that the amount of value I will need to buffer will be relatively low. I don't want to put a value because I don7t know exactly how many, but I think it will never be over a thousand.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L22